# Where exported CSV file is saved?

Tags: android

I am trying to export my database to **CSV** file on external storage, but nothing happens when I click on my "Export data!" button.

Here is the code:

**SpsActivity**.java

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bStart:
            start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    minutes = millisUntilFinished / 60000;
                    seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    counter.setText("Remaining: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter.setText("Done!");
                    export.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }.start();
            break;
        case R.id.bExport:
            ExportDatabaseCSVTask task = new ExportDatabaseCSVTask();
            task.execute();
            break;
        }
    }

private class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                SpsActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
            this.dialog.show();

        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            File dbFile = getDatabasePath("brojanje.db");
            DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(
                    getApplicationContext());
            Log.v("SpsActivity", "Db path is: " + dbFile); // get the path of db

            File exportDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
            if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(exportDir, "brojanje.csv");
            try {

                file.createNewFile();
                CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(); // Cursor
                Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM izlazniRezultati.db",
                        null);
                csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
                while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                    String arrStr[] = { curCSV.getString(0),
                            curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                            curCSV.getString(3) };
                    csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                }
                csvWrite.close();
                curCSV.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
                Log.e("SpsActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(SpsActivity.this, "Export successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SpsActivity.this, "Export failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for my DATABASE:
**DatabaseHandler**.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SMEROVI = "Smerovi";
    public static final String KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA = "Kategorizacija";
    public static final String KEY_VREDNOSTI = "Vrednosti";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "brojanje.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "izlazniRezultati";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_SMEROVI
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VREDNOSTI + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createEntry(String smer, String kat, String vrednost){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SMEROVI, smer);
        values.put(KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA, kat);
        values.put(KEY_VREDNOSTI, vrednost);

        //ask the database object to insert the new data
        try {
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

So, I exported signed application, and tested it on my phone. There is no exported file in my phone. I guess it's some obvious error, but I am going crazy here, so please if you can help I'do appreciate!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert it to .db and import it in your ddms n use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra ".db" here

```
Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM izlazniRezultati.db",
```

it should be:

```
Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM izlazniRezultati",
```

**[EDIT]**

Since that wasn't the only issue, I'm showing you how I do the very same thing, more or less:

This is in my Main Activity (in your case, SpsActivity ?) - called in the AsyncTask

```
private final void dataExport()
{
    /* Save a headerless csv file from the db, separated by ";" an terminated by "\n"). */

    final Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

    final String appPath = String.format
        (
            "%s/YourAppName", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        );

            final File path = new File(appPath);
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        path.mkdir();
    }

    final String fileBAK = String.format("%s/backup.csv", appPath);
    final String str = CLS_DB.dataExport(ctx);

    final int len = str.length();

    //final int rows = str.split("\n").length;

    if (len > 0)
    {
        // Write the backup file
        try
        {
            final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileBAK));
            try
            {
                fos.write(str.getBytes());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (final IOException e)
            {
                /*
                System.out.println
                (
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n" + e.getCause()
                );
                */
                // Do something to inform the users that you couldn't export the data
            }
        }
        catch(final FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // Do something to inform the users that you couldn't export the data
        }
    }
}
```

This is in my DBHelper class (CLS_DB) - yes, the method name is the very same, due to a fantasy shortage... ;)

```
// Export all data
protected final static String dataExport(final Context ctx)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        final Cursor cur = db.rawQuery
            (
                "SELECT * FROM izlazniRezultati ORDER BY Smerovi ASC", null
            );
        if (cur != null)
        {
            if (cur.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    sb.append
                    (
                        String.format
                        (
                            "%s;%s\n",
                            cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Smerovi")),
                            cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Kategorizacija")),
                            cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Vrednosti")),
                    );
                }
                while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cur.close();
    }
    catch (final SQLiteException se)
    {
        System.out.println
        (
            ctx.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\n" + "Could not read from the database"
        );
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

What it does, in short:

- It reads the data from the db
- It packs it into a big string, with the ";" value separators (as interpreted by Excel) and the "\n" line terminators
- It prepares the path and the file
- Then it writes the string all at once in the file on the sd card

It's a bit long, but very simple to follow.

Please not that I didn't include the _id field in the export (I don't have it, nor I think you would need it in Excel), but you can easily add it to the StringBuilder, while preparing the exported string.

I forgot to mention... the straight answer to your question is:
With this code, the csv file is exported in `/mnt/sdcard/YourAppName/backup.csv` (or whatever your predefined storage is mounted/linked)

**[EDIT 2]**

I gave for granted that you had this permission set in your Manifest file:

```
<!-- To write and read to and from SDCard -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If not, set it - it's required to read/write from/to your sd card.

Comment: I tried like this, but it's the same situation. File hasn't been exported.

Comment: Well, it appears that you are using a 3rd party library to do something that sincerely I'd do with what the language offers (FileOutputStream). Anyway, your code appears to be correct, to me (not knowing the CSVWriter object)

Comment: I need this to be file that I will be able to open with Excel for further operations. So, can you suggest some other option?

Comment: I do the same thong differently, but can't use a few lines to describe it. I must write an answer.

Comment: I'd appreciate a lot. This is the only thing stoping me from releasing my application. :(

Comment: I am getting an error in MainActivity - "path cannot be resolved" for this: `if(!path.exists())
    {
        path.mkdir();
    }`
Thank you for helping me. :)

Comment: After this line, `final String fileBAK = String.format("%s/backup.csv", appPath);`, can you do a `System.out.println(fileBAK);` and post it?

Comment: I cannot even run or debug application because of this error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my fault. I'm correcting my answer immediately! OK, done - Added the **missing line** before the control `if(!path.exists())`

Comment: Still not working. There is no file that should be exported. :(

Comment: Now, please, after this line, `final String fileBAK = String.format("%s/backup.csv", appPath);`, can you do a `System.out.println(fileBAK);` and post it?

Comment: Nothing happens on Console when I click on button "Export Data!". In my case `R.id.bExport` I simply called exportData function like this: `exportData();`, is it ok? I don't know what can it be, but it's pretty annoying.

Comment: Have you put that line? System.out.println... I need to know what's wrong in your path...

Comment: ONE MOMENT!! You probably miss a permission in your Manifest - I gave for sure you already had it, but now I have a serious doubt. Add this to your Manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` - I also updated my answer.

Comment: Yea, I did, but nothing happened.

Comment: It's probably because of the missing permission. I'm going now, it's 21:06 here... I'll be back in about 12 hrs, if still not solved (but I guess this time it's all fixed).

Comment: That's not the problem, I already had that line in my Manifest. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't control your PC from here. I'll sleep on the question, maybe tomorrow morning I'm fresher - but it really SHOULD WORK (I use that code without problems). Try running it on a device instead of an emulator (sometimes emulators lock their sd cards)

Comment: Everything here has been done on my phone (LG Optimus L9), not the emulator.
I can post entire code of my SpsActivity if you like, maybe something else is causing the problem?

Comment: I haven't mentioned, I do not have SD card in my phone. I want to save it on Internal storage. I don't think this has anything to do with the problem, cause I've read official documentation and it says that it is not just external storage as SDcard, but internal storage.

Comment: I've tried creating new project and put only two buttons on the screen (one to Save data to database, and another to export data), and it worked perfectly!
So, I checked **Console** a little bit at my original application in which I have problem. It seems there is kinda warning **Skipped 23 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread**.
What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Skipping frames is due to much work on the main thread. Move some code in another thread, put some in AsyncTasks...

Comment: And, no, the internal storage isn't an issue. It will be seen as the external storage, if this one is missing.

Comment: It's a best practice, to unload the main thread from too much weight... ;)

Comment: @Der_Golem, I can't make this work. Can you take a look at my whole code to see if something is unusual to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, not now. Since I'm going out in a few minutes. But tomorrow morning I can.

Comment: Part of exporting data from SQLite. Code for exporting data from SQLite has worked just fine when I made new Project with one button (when I click it it adds something to the database) and another button to export data.
I'll put my code in an answer, so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.mmilosanovic.trafficcounting;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener,
        OnClickListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    CheckBox TV, BUS, AV, MOT;
    Button start, export;
    TextView counter;
    float startX = 0;
    float startY = 0;
    float finishX = 0;
    float finishY = 0;
    int pomocZaSve = 0;
    int pomocZaCekiranje = 0;
    long seconds, minutes;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        export = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bExport);
        export.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
        counter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        TV = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbTV);
        BUS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBUS);
        AV = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbAV);
        MOT = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMOT);
        TV.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        BUS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        AV.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        MOT.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureDetector());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bStart:
            start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    minutes = millisUntilFinished / 60000;
                    seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    counter.setText("Remaining: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter.setText("Done!");
                    export.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }.start();
            break;
        case R.id.bExport:
            ExportDatabaseCSVTask task = new ExportDatabaseCSVTask();
            task.execute();
            break;
        }
    }

    private class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
            this.dialog.show();

        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            File dbFile = getDatabasePath("brojanje");
            DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(
                    getApplicationContext());
            Log.v("SpsActivity", "Db path is: " + dbFile); // get the path of db

            File exportDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
            if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(exportDir, "brojanje.csv");
            try {

                file.createNewFile();
                CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(); // Cursor
                Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM izlazniRezultati",
                        null);
                csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
                while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                    String arrStr[] = { curCSV.getString(0),
                            curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                            curCSV.getString(3) };
                    csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                }
                csvWrite.close();
                curCSV.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
                Log.e("SpsActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Export successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Export failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float height = metrics.heightPixels;
        float width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        width = metrics.widthPixels;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = event.getRawX();
            startY = event.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            finishX = event.getRawX();
            finishY = event.getRawY();
            float X1zbirX2 = startX + finishX;
            float Y1zbirY2 = startY + finishY;
            float X1aritmetickaX2 = X1zbirX2 / 2;
            float Y1aritmetickaY2 = Y1zbirY2 / 2;
            // drugi kvartal (koordinate sredine povucene linije/dijagonale)
            if (X1aritmetickaX2 > (width / 2) && Y1aritmetickaY2 < (height / 2)) {
                pomocZaSve = 1;
                // cetvrti kvartal
            } else if (X1aritmetickaX2 < (width / 2)
                    && Y1aritmetickaY2 > (height / 2)) {
                pomocZaSve = 2;
                // treci kvartal
            } else if (X1aritmetickaX2 > (width / 2)
                    && Y1aritmetickaY2 > (height / 2)) {
                pomocZaSve = 3;
                // prvi kvartal
            } else if (X1aritmetickaX2 < (width / 2)
                    && Y1aritmetickaY2 < (height / 2)) {
                pomocZaSve = 4;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.cbTV:
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 1;
            } else {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 5;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cbBUS:
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 2;
            } else {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 6;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cbAV:
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 3;
            } else {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 7;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cbMOT:
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 4;
            } else {
                pomocZaCekiranje = 8;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void onSwipeLeft() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DESNO LEVO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-4", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-4", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-4", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-4", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-4", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeRight() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "LEVO DESNO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-2", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-2", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-2", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-2", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-2", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeTop() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DOLE GORE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-1", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-1", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-1", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-1", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-1", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error");
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeBottom() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "GORE DOLE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-3", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-3", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-3", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-3", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-3", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromBottomToLeft() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DOLE LEVO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-4", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-4", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-4", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-4", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-4", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromTopToRight() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "GORE DESNO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-2", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-2", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-2", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-2", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-2", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromTopToLeft() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "GORE LEVO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-4", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-4", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-4", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-4", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 1-4", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromBottomToRight() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DOLE DESNO");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-2", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-2", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-2", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-2", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 3-2", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromRightToTop() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DESNO GORE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-1", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-1", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-1", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-1", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-1", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromRightToBottom() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "DESNO DOLE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-3", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-3", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-3", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-3", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 2-3", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromLeftToTop() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "LEVO GORE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-1", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-1", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-1", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-1", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-1", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void onSwipeFromLeftToBottom() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "LEVO DOLE");

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (pomocZaCekiranje == 1) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-3", "TV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    TV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 2) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-3", "BUS", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    BUS.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 3) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-3", "AV", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    AV.toggle();
                } else if (pomocZaCekiranje == 4) {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-3", "MOT", 1);
                    entry.close();
                    MOT.toggle();
                } else {
                    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.createEntry("Smer 4-3", "PA", 1);
                    entry.close();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    // Private class for gestures
    private class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
        private static final int SWIPE_X = 30;
        private static final int SWIPE_Y = 50;
        private static final int SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X = 80;
        private static final int SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y = 80;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();

                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)
                        && Math.abs(diffY) < SWIPE_X) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > Math.abs(diffX)
                        && Math.abs(diffX) < SWIPE_Y) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    // iz donjeg kraka u levi krak
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 2
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX > finishX && startY > finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromBottomToLeft();
                    // iz gornjeg kraka u desni krak
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 1
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX < finishX && startY < finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromTopToRight();
                    // iz gornjeg kraka u levi krak
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 4
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX > finishX && startY < finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromTopToLeft();
                    // iz donjeg kraka u desni krak
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 3
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX < finishX && startY > finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromBottomToRight();
                    // iz desnog kraka u gornji
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 1
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX > finishX && startY > finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromRightToTop();
                    // iz desnog kraka u donji krak
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 3
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX > finishX && startY < finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromRightToBottom();
                    // iz levog kraka u gornji
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 4
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX < finishX && startY > finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromLeftToTop();
                    // iz levog kraka u donji
                } else if (pomocZaSve == 2
                        && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_X
                        && Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_DIJAGONALA_Y
                        && startX < finishX && startY < finishY) {
                    onSwipeFromLeftToBottom();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error on gestures");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is **DatabaseHelper.java**:

```
package com.mmilosanovic.trafficcounting;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SMEROVI = "Smerovi";
    public static final String KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA = "Kategorizacija";
    public static final String KEY_VREDNOSTI = "Vrednosti";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "brojanje";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "izlazniRezultati";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_SMEROVI
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VREDNOSTI + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createEntry(String smer, String kat, int vrednost){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SMEROVI, smer);
        values.put(KEY_KATEGORIZACIJA, kat);
        values.put(KEY_VREDNOSTI, vrednost);

        //ask the database object to insert the new data
        try {
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the `CSVWriter` object, since I use to write my text files **directly**. Anyway, your export code seems just correct, to me. Only that I would add: `curCSV.moveToFirst();` before  `csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());`

Comment: That's not the problem. I think it is something about the message I am getting - "Too much work on main thread". I ran out of ideas here. :/

Comment: I do the query in my dbHelper class, from which I return the comma separated and line terminated "big string" (built using a StringBuilder) to the calling activity's file writing method.

Comment: I made it work. Problem was in Export button (don't know why exactly), I just called the function for exporting csv file in SAVE button and it worked perfectly.
@Der Golem, thanks a lot for your help here. :)