# Cannot find exported SQLite DB in CSV on device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

I've implemented an SQLite table in my app, and now want to export it out into the device itself.

I followed very similiar code to this:
[Where exported CSV file is saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657482/where-exported-csv-file-is-saved)

and this:
http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/database-table-export-to-csv-in-android.html

And yet, no matter how I tinker, the CSV file does not show up on my device. I do not have an sd card mounted, but as external storage is now simulated it shouldn't matter correct?

Export method:

```
private void exportDB() {

    File dbFile = getDatabasePath("emotionSQLTable.db");
    EmotionListDbHelper dbhelper = new EmotionListDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    //switching out to internal directory here, for debu purposes and because we dont have sd card
    final String appPath = String.format
            (
                    "%s/Aletheia", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            );

    File exportDir = new File(appPath);
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date());
    //TODO for debugging purposes
    File file = new File(exportDir, "emotionSQLTable.csv");
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Here we select from the TABLE NAME, which is emotionlist
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM emotionlist", null);
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
        while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
            //Which column you want to exprort
            String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }
        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }


}
```

DBHelper class

```
public class EmotionListDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "emotionSQLTable.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public EmotionListDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String SQL_CREATE_WAITLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE emotionlist(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, anger DOUBLE NOT NULL, contempt DOUBLE NOT NULL, disgust DOUBLE NOT NULL, fear DOUBLE NOT NULL, happiness DOUBLE NOT NULL, neutral DOUBLE NOT NULL, sadness DOUBLE NOT NULL, surprise DOUBLE NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE emotionlist(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, anger DOUBLE NOT NULL, contempt DOUBLE NOT NULL, disgust DOUBLE NOT NULL, fear DOUBLE NOT NULL, happiness DOUBLE NOT NULL, neutral DOUBLE NOT NULL, sadness DOUBLE NOT NULL, surprise DOUBLE NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emotionlist");
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

So far, I've tried moving the code into an AsyncTask, storing it in the internal memory, to no avail. any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the issue here was not the SQLite code. It was a bug with the button onClickListener itself. The button was not calling the method at all.